# Vertically align buttons with textarea

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In following `bootstrap-3` html the three `buttons` are aligned to the top edge of `textarea`. How can we align in the middle instead so they are about half way down?

Note: It probably is not relevant but just in case, I'm using default bootstrap settings in a [Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/welcome-to-visual-studio) project.

[image]

```
<tr class="row">
    <td class="col-md-8">
        <textarea class="txtInput form-control" rows="3" asp-for="@Model.lstOrders" style="min-width:630px;overflow:auto;"></textarea>
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-4 text-right">
        <button type="button" class="btnEdit btn-info btn-xs">Edit</button> |
        <button type="button" class="Savebtn btn-info btn-xs" value="@Model.lstOrders">Save</button> |
        <button type="button" class="btnResetOrginVal btn-info btn-xs">Reset</button> | <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Delete</button>
<tr>
```

Comment: Could you show the expected output?

Comment: have you tried: `td {vertical-align:middle;}` ? this is the basic and should work. If not show us more :)

Comment: @G-Cyr Your suggestion worked (thanks).

Comment: @Win Thank you for trying to help.The expected output is the same as shown in  `@G-Cyr`'s response below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented earlier :Within table-cells, `td {vertical-align:middle;}` should do .

```css
td {vertical-align:middle;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table>
<tr class="row">
    <td class="col-md-8">
        <textarea class="txtInput form-control" rows="3" asp-for="@Model.lstOrders" style="min-width:300px;overflow:auto;"></textarea>
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-4 text-right">
        <button type="button" class="btnEdit btn-info btn-xs">Edit</button> |
        <button type="button" class="Savebtn btn-info btn-xs" value="@Model.lstOrders">Save</button> |
        <button type="button" class="btnResetOrginVal btn-info btn-xs">Reset</button> | <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Delete</button>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, setting your `td`s to `vertical-align: middle` (which is the initial property value anyway) should do the trick.

```css
.specialTable td {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<table class="specialTable">
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="col-md-8">
      <textarea class="txtInput form-control" rows="3" asp-for="@Model.lstOrders" style="overflow:auto;"></textarea>
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-4 text-right">
      <button type="button" class="btnEdit btn-info btn-xs">Edit</button> |
      <button type="button" class="Savebtn btn-info btn-xs" value="@Model.lstOrders">Save</button> |
      <button type="button" class="btnResetOrginVal btn-info btn-xs">Reset</button> | <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Delete</button>
  </tr>
</table>
```